# Angular cross-service communication

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I have a statistics application. On the left side of my page I have list of themes, on the top - list of groups. The main part contains statistics items related to both theme and group.

Also I have several services which provide business logic for my application. For simplicity let's talk about three of them: *ThemeSerivce, GroupService* and *StatisticsService*.

End users could manipulate lists of themes and groups (add or remove items) and I have to recalculate statistics after each change. In this application I use *Subjects* and *Subsription* from *rx.js* to track such kind of changes.

So, in my components I could write something like this:

for *GroupComponent*

```
 removeGroup() {
        this.groupService.removeGroup(this.group);
        this.statisticsService.updateStatistics();
      }
```

for *ThemeComponent*

```
removeTheme() {
    this.themeService.removeTheme(this.theme);
    this.statisticsService.updateStatistics();
  }
```

But logically these components don't have to know about statistics. Of course I can move dependency of *StatisticsService* into *ThemeService* and *GroupService*, but then I will have to call *statisticsService.updateStatistics()* in every method which changes collection of themes or groups. That's why I want to implement direct cross-service communication with subscription.

And finally my questions:

1. Is it a good idea at all?
2. If it's ok, what is the best way to implement it?
   When I use *Subscription* in components, I register it in *ngOnInit()* method and unsubscribe in *ngOnDestroy()* to prevent memory leaks.
   Could I subscribe it in service's constructor? And when or where should I unsubscribe? Or maybe it's not necessary when I register my services as provider on App module level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StatisticsService` should subscribe to the list of themes and groups.  Your individual components should only subscribe to their respective services (ThemeComponent to ThemeService, Group to Group etc).

For simplicity, I'll just focus on the `ThemeService` but `GroupService` is similar.  `ThemeService` should have an internal `Subject` when remove is called, the `Subject` will next a value (probably the entire new list).

`StatisticsService` will subscribe to the `ThemeService` observable and recalculate after change.  It will look something like this

```
/* theme.service.ts */
@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {
    private _list$ = new Subject<ThemeList>();

    get list(): Observable<ThemeList> {
        return this._list$.asObservable();
    }

    set list(newList: ThemeList) {
       this._list$.next(newList);
    }
}


/* statistics.service.ts */
@Injectable()
export class StatisticsService {
    private _calculation$ = new Subject<StatisticResult>();

    constructor(private themeService: ThemeService) {
        themeService.list.subscribe((themeList: ThemeList) => this.updateCalculation(themeList));
    }

    get calculation(): Observable<StatisticResult> {
        return this._calculation$.asObservable();
    }

    updateCalculation(newData: ThemeList | GroupList) {
        // ... do stuff
        this._calculation.next(statisticResult);
    }
}


/* statistics.component.ts */
@Component({
  selector: 'statistics',
  template: '<p>{{ statisticResult$ | async }}</p>'
})
export class StatisticsComponent {
    statisticResult$: Observable<StatisticResult>;

    constructor(private statisticsService: StatisticsService) {
        this.statisticResult$ = statisticsService.calculation;
    }
}
```