# Cross-service communication on Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, singleton, subject

I have two services that depends on each other, let's say `serviceA` and `serviceB`. `serviceA` perform a action method from a component call and have to emit a value in the end of the process. This emission is listened from `serviceB` and then it have to update its methods. I did as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975816/angular-cross-service-communication) but `subject` does not seems to work between services.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
  // Observable source
  private textSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable stream
  text$ = this.textSource.asObservable();

  methodCalledFromComp() {
    // does some work
    this.textSource.next('someValue');
  }
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServiceB {
  constructor(private serviceA: ServiceA) {
    serviceA.text$.subscribe(el => {
      // not comes here, only when I call the same from a method
      console.log(el);
    });
  }
```

I did a test on component listening from this emission and it worked. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any alternative?

Comment: What did you mean *"does not seems to work"*? Give a [mre].

Comment: I did an update.

Comment: First, rename `construct` to `constructor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may be happening to you is that service B has never been initialized in the application, it has happened to me.

I have created a demo here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cross-service-communication-on-angular)

Comment: Was exactly what I need. I did not know there should be at least one injection to a service be initialized. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set those services as singletons with
`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

I've just created a demo here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cross-service-demo)

Comment: Thanks, it worked too. I was not expecting at least one injection of the service to work. As I need the services to be scoped I gave the acceptance to Juan. But really thanks!